# Fill missing values with previous values by row using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am working with a dataframe in R which has some missing values across rows. Data frame is next (`dput` added in the end):

```
df
  id V1 V2 V3 V4
1 01  1  1  1 NA
2 02  2  1 NA NA
3 03  3  1 NA NA
4 04  4  1  2 NA
```

Each row is a different `id`. As you can see the rows have missing values. I would like to know how can I get a dataframe completed in this style **without using reshape to long or pivot as my real data is very large**:

```
df
  id V1 V2 V3 V4
1 01  1  1  1  1
2 02  2  1  1  1
3 03  3  1  1  1
4 04  4  1  2  2
```

I was trying to use `fill` from `tidyr` but at row level I am having issues. I have seen some posts where it is used along with `dplyr` function `across` but I can not find it. I have tried using `group_by(id)` and `rowwise` but I have not had success. Also only the variables/columns starting with `V` should be filled with previous values.

Data is next:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(id = c("01", "02", "03", "04"), V1 = c(1, 2, 3, 
4), V2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), V3 = c(1, NA, NA, 2), V4 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution could be using `na.locf` function from package `zoo` combining with `purrr::pmap` function in a row-wise operation. `na.locf` takes the most recent non-`NA` value and replace all the upcoming `NA` values by that. Just as a reminder `c(...)` in both solutions captures all values of `V1:V4` in each row in every iteration. However, I excluded `id` column in both as it is not involved in the our calculations.

```
library(zoo)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(pmap_df(., ~ na.locf(c(...)[-1])))

  id V1 V2 V3 V4
1 01  1  1  1  1
2 02  2  1  1  1
3 03  3  1  1  1
4 04  4  1  2  2
```

Or we can use `coalesce` function from `dplyr`. We can replace every `NA` values in each row with the last non-`NA` value, something we did earlier with `na.locf`. However this solution is a bit verbose:

```
df %>%
  mutate(pmap_df(., ~ {x <- c(...)[!is.na(c(...))]; 
  coalesce(c(...), x[length(x)])}))

  id V1 V2 V3 V4
1 01  1  1  1  1
2 02  2  1  1  1
3 03  3  1  1  1
4 04  4  1  2  2
```

Or you could also use this:

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(!id, ~ replace(., is.na(.), invoke(coalesce, rev(df[-1])))))

  id V1 V2 V3 V4
1 01  1  1  1  1
2 02  2  1  1  1
3 03  3  1  1  1
4 04  4  1  2  2
```

The warning message can be ignored. It is in fact produced because we have 6 `NA` values but the result of applying `dplyr::coalesce` on every vector is 1 element resulting in 4 elements to replace 6 slots.

Comment: If it is pmap, it has to be Anoush.  Good work

Comment: hahaha That's very kind of you dear friend.

Comment: Thank you mannnn! That's very kind of you :)

Comment: take a look here. you are getting famous! <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68913278/selecting-values-from-specific-columns-and-skipping-na-values-in-r/68914759?noredirect=1#comment121793354_68914759>

Comment: Come onnn don't make fun of me you two are being super nice :D

Answer (score 8):

One option using `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(across(-id, ~ ifelse(is.na(.), coalesce(!!!select(., V4:V1)), .)))

  id V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  1  1  1
3  3  3  1  1  1
4  4  4  1  2  2
```

Comment: Dear Thomas would you please let me know what big bang operator does here? I tried it and apparently turned values into `FALSE`.

Comment: What the `!!!` or big gang operator does is splicing the elements of the list, meaning that each become a single argument.

Comment: I always called it the "bang bang bang" operator, but "big bang" is so much better.

Comment: @IanCampbell I'm using it extensively but never thought about using it in situation like this.

Answer (score 5):

A `dplyr` approach

```r
df <- structure(list(id = c("01", "02", "03", "04"), V1 = c(1, 2, 3, 
                                                            4), V2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), V3 = c(1, NA, NA, 2), V4 = c(NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                 NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))


library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

df %>% mutate(across(V1:V4, ~ coalesce(., tail(cur_data()[-1][!is.na(cur_data()[-1])],1))))
#>   id V1 V2 V3 V4
#> 1 01  1  1  1  2
#> 2 02  2  1  2  2
#> 3 03  3  1  2  2
#> 4 04  4  1  2  2
```

If you'll `group_by` on `id` column, you won't have to use `[-1] on` cur_data()`

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(V1:V4, ~ coalesce(., tail(cur_data()[!is.na(cur_data())],1))))
```

Answer (score 5):

If the reason you want to avoid reshaping is to save runtime then that idea is actually mistaken if the benchmark below continues to hold at scale.  Note that f which transposes, uses na.locf and then transposes back is the fastest.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(zoo)

microbenchmark(times = 10,
  a = df %>% mutate(pmap_df(., ~ na.locf(c(...)[-1]))),
  b = df %>%
    mutate(pmap_df(., ~ {x <- c(...)[!is.na(c(...))]; 
    coalesce(c(...), x[length(x)])})),
  c = df %>%
    mutate(across(-id, ~ ifelse(is.na(.), coalesce(!!!select(., V4:V1)), .))),
  d = df %>% mutate(across(V1:V4, ~ coalesce(., tail(cur_data()[-1][!is.na(cur_data()[-1])],1)))),
  e = as.data.table(df)[, setNames(as.list(nafill(unlist(.SD), type = "locf")), names(.SD)), id],
  f = data.frame(id = df$id, t(na.locf(t(df[-1])))))
```

giving:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    a 11.343302 12.934702 15.032001 13.115151 14.799400 30.135901    10
    b 11.641301 13.116401 14.030551 14.426751 15.012701 15.517501    10
    c 28.201501 30.470801 33.375761 32.672950 36.671101 40.448701    10
    d 25.394901 26.648801 30.044331 27.971251 32.433801 39.570600    10
    e  3.750801  4.023700  8.771401  4.150701  4.367502 50.636700    10
    f  2.454701  2.458201  3.009181  2.603951  2.952302  6.126101    10
```

Answer (score 4):

A `data.table` option with `nafill`

```
> setDT(df)[, setNames(as.list(nafill(unlist(.SD), type = "locf")), names(.SD)), id]
   id V1 V2 V3 V4
1: 01  1  1  1  1
2: 02  2  1  1  1
3: 03  3  1  1  1
4: 04  4  1  2  2
```