# How to adjust specifications for output table generation

Tags: r

I have a question regarding the code below. The code below generates an output dataset, which is being generated correctly. However, note that I am using `'DRM00'`. I find it strange that if I insert just `'DRM'`, the output table is incorrect. Do you know why? This will be a problem for me if I have, for example, `DRM012` in my dataset, since in the code I just specify `'DRM00'`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- structure(list(date1 = c("2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"), 
                      date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05","2021-07-10","2021-07-13","2021-07-20","2021-07-22"), 
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","FDE"), 
                      Week = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Sunday","Thursday","Wednesday","Saturday","Sunday"), 
                      DR1 = c(4, 1, 6, 3, 3, 1,2,4), DRM001 = c(4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4,1,4), DRM002 = c(4, 2, 6, 2, 2, 1,2,2), 
                      DRM003 = c(9, 5, 4, 7,3, 3,3,2), DRM004 = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 8,2,2), DRM005 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5,4,4), 
                      DRM006 = c(2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5,4,2),DRM007 = c(1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5,4,5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2<- structure(list(date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05","2021-07-10","2021-07-13","2021-07-20","2021-07-22"), 
                     Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","FDE"), coef = c(4, 1, 6, 3, 6, 5, 11,14)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("date2", "Category")) %>%
  select(-c(Week, DR1)) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("DR"), ~ coef - .),
         across(contains("date"), ymd),
         datedif = parse_number(as.character(date2-date1)),
         across(starts_with("DR"), .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'DRM00', 'DR_')}")) %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Result = if (str_c('DR_', datedif) %in% names(.)) get(str_c('DR_', datedif)) else coef) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(date2, Category, coef, Result)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  date2      Category  coef Result
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-06-30 FDE          4      0
2 2021-06-30 ABC          1     -1
3 2021-07-04 FDE          6      3
4 2021-07-05 ABC          3      1
5 2021-07-10 ABC          6      6
6 2021-07-13 ABC          5      5
7 2021-07-20 ABC         11     11
8 2021-07-22 FDE         14     14
```

If I used just `'DRM'`, the output table is incorrect, as you see below.

```
df1 %>% 
      left_join(df2, by = c("date2", "Category")) %>%
      select(-c(Week, DR1)) %>% 
      mutate(across(starts_with("DR"), ~ coef - .),
             across(contains("date"), ymd),
             datedif = parse_number(as.character(date2-date1)),
             across(starts_with("DR"), .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'DRM', 'DR_')}")) %>% 
      rowwise %>%
      mutate(Result = if (str_c('DR_', datedif) %in% names(.)) get(str_c('DR_', datedif)) else coef) %>%
      ungroup() %>% 
      select(date2, Category, coef, Result)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  date2      Category  coef Result
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-06-30 FDE          4      4
2 2021-06-30 ABC          1      1
3 2021-07-04 FDE          6      6
4 2021-07-05 ABC          3      3
5 2021-07-10 ABC          6      6
6 2021-07-13 ABC          5      5
7 2021-07-20 ABC         11     11
8 2021-07-22 FDE         14     14
```

**New Database 1**

```
df1 <- structure(list(date1 = c("2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"), 
                      date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05","2021-07-10","2021-07-13","2021-07-20","2021-07-22"), 
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","FDE"), 
                      Week = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Sunday","Thursday","Wednesday","Saturday","Sunday"), 
                      DR1 = c(4, 1, 6, 3, 3, 1,2,4), DRM001 = c(4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4,1,4), DRM002 = c(4, 2, 6, 2, 2, 1,2,2), 
                      DRM003 = c(9, 5, 4, 7,3, 3,3,2), DRM004 = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 8,2,2), DRM005 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5,4,4), 
                      DRM006 = c(2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5,4,2),DRM007 = c(1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5,4,5),DRM008 = c(1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5,1,5),DRM009 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5,4,5),
                      DRM010 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5,2,5),DRM011 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1,4,5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

**New database 2**

```
df1 <- structure(list(date1 = c("2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"), 
                      date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05","2021-07-10","2021-07-13","2021-07-20","2021-07-22"), 
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","FDE"), 
                      Week = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Sunday","Thursday","Wednesday","Saturday","Sunday"), 
                      DR1 = c(4, 1, 6, 3, 3, 1,2,4), DRM01 = c(4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4,1,4), DRM02 = c(4, 2, 6, 2, 2, 1,2,2), 
                      DRM03 = c(9, 5, 4, 7,3, 3,3,2), DRM04 = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 8,2,2), DRM05 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5,4,4), 
                      DRM06 = c(2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5,4,2),DRM07 = c(1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5,4,5),DRM08 = c(1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5,1,5),DRM09 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5,4,5),
                      DRM10 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5,2,5),DRM011 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1,4,5),DRM12 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1,4,5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2<- structure(list(date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05","2021-07-10","2021-07-13","2021-07-20","2021-07-22"), 
                     Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","FDE"), coef = c(4, 1, 6, 3, 6, 5, 11,14)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

When I run your code for `Database` 2, the following error appears:

```
Error: Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:
  * "DRM1" at locations 4 and 13.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2:** :-(

The problem was the regular expression `'0+'`
Changed to `'(?<=[A-Z])0+(?=.)'` with assist from @Tim Biegeleisen [How to remove all zeros before first non-zero number WITHIN a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70516322/how-to-remove-all-zeros-before-first-non-zero-number-within-a-string)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("date2", "Category")) %>%
  select(-c(Week, DR1)) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("DR"), ~ coef - .),
         across(contains("date"), ymd),
         datedif = parse_number(as.character(date2-date1))
  ) %>% 
  rename_with(~str_replace(.,'(?<=[A-Z])0+(?=.)', ""),starts_with('DR')) %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Result = if (str_c('DRM', datedif) %in% names(.)) get(str_c('DRM', datedif)) else coef) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(date2, Category, coef, Result)

  date2      Category  coef Result
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-06-30 FDE          4      0
2 2021-06-30 ABC          1     -1
3 2021-07-04 FDE          6      3
4 2021-07-05 ABC          3      1
5 2021-07-10 ABC          6      4
6 2021-07-13 ABC          5      5
7 2021-07-20 ABC         11     11
8 2021-07-22 FDE         14     14
```

I checked the result visually:
[image]

**Udate1:** :-)

With `rename_with(~str_replace(.,'0+', ""),starts_with('DR'))` now we should be independent of what your `DRM` is called. That said, it should not matter if `DRM0003` or `DRM010` or `DRM00110` etc...

Then we have also to change `DR_` to `DRM` in

```
mutate(Result = if (str_c('DR_', datedif) %in% names(.)) get(str_c('DR_', datedif)) else coef) %>%
```

```
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("date2", "Category")) %>%
  select(-c(Week, DR1)) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("DR"), ~ coef - .),
         across(contains("date"), ymd),
         datedif = parse_number(as.character(date2-date1))
  ) %>% 
  rename_with(~str_replace(.,'0+', ""),starts_with('DR')) %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Result = if (str_c('DRM', datedif) %in% names(.)) get(str_c('DRM', datedif)) else coef) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(date2, Category, coef, Result)
```

```
  date2      Category  coef Result
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-06-30 FDE          4      0
2 2021-06-30 ABC          1     -1
3 2021-07-04 FDE          6      3
4 2021-07-05 ABC          3      1
5 2021-07-10 ABC          6      6
6 2021-07-13 ABC          5      5
7 2021-07-20 ABC         11     11
8 2021-07-22 FDE         14     14
```

Comment: So, let me try to explain it better. There in your code you specify  `'DRM00'`, correct? But what if, for example, I have a database equal to the one I entered in the question, which has `DRM010` and `DRM011`. Do you agree that these two will not be included in the analysis as they are not `DRM00`?

Comment: Yes I agree and I am working right now to solve this!

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: Thanks for reply @Tarjae, but the output table is not right. The correct output table is the first one I inserted there in the question, where for 06/30, for example, it has a `coef` equal to 4 and a `Result` equal to `0`. As you are doing, for all dates, notice that the `coef` value is equal to `Result`.

Comment: Please see my update. This is really fun. Now after some sleep I see it clearly. Now it should work. :-)

Comment: It's amazing how getting some sleep helps clear our minds. Your answer is right, however, I am having a little problem regarding names in a database I am testing. I inserted above to see. See that this database instead of having `DRM001` is `DRM01`. However, in my perception your code would have to work too, however getting the following error: `DRM1" at locations 4 and 13`.

Comment: Sorry missed your last comment. Now hopefully it should work. If not please tell.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, I traveled yesterday. Perfect resolution, thanks for solving one more question for me. Thank you so much! =)

Comment: So happy that it worked. :-)

Comment: can you help with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71528512/how-to-adjust-function-without-specifying-dataset