# How to remove all zeros before first non-zero number WITHIN a string

Tags: r, regex

**I have** the following vector with strings:

```
strings <- c("ABC0001", "ABC02", "ABC10", "ABC01010", "ABC11", "ABC011", "ABC0120")

"ABC0001"  "ABC02"    "ABC10"    "ABC01010" "ABC11"    "ABC011"   "ABC0120"
```

**Desired output:**

```
[1] "ABC1"    "ABC2"    "ABC10"   "ABC1010" "ABC11"   "ABC11"   "ABC120"
```

**My question: What is the regular expression pattern for zeros before first integer in a string?**

So far I have tried:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(strings,'0+', "")
```

which gives:

```
[1] "ABC1"    "ABC2"    "ABC1"    "ABC1010" "ABC11"   "ABC11"   "ABC120"
```

Note: Not desired `ABC1` in position 3. Should be `ABC10`
I suspect this might be easy, but I can't get it.

**I want to learn the regular expression pattern!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `sub`, with lookarounds:

```r
strings <- c("ABC0001", "ABC02", "ABC10", "ABC01010", "ABC11", "ABC011", "ABC0120")
output <- sub("(?<=[A-Z])0+(?=.)", "", strings, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "ABC1"    "ABC2"    "ABC10"   "ABC1010" "ABC11"   "ABC11"   "ABC120"
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern being used:

```regex
(?<=[A-Z])  assert that an uppercase letter precedes
0+          match one or more zeroes
(?=.)       assert that some character follows
```

The `(?<=.)` and `(?=.)` are called *lookarounds*.  In this case, they make sure that the `0` we target are not at the very start or very end of the input value.  For an input like `ABC110`, we want the output to be `ABC110`, i.e. the final zero should not be removed.

Comment: I am trying to understand your codes and regex in general.  What exactly `+(?=.)` does? I tried `sub("0+(?=.)", "", strings, perl=TRUE)` to understand your codes step by step, and it also gives the same output by the way.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Maybe you could explain the regex? And with your answer you helped solving this question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503223/how-to-adjust-specifications-for-output-table-generation/70503360?noredirect=1#comment124636107_70503360>

Comment: An headsup Tim, but I noticed this would delete zero's in `"ABC1001"`. Not sure if data like that is likely with OP though.

Comment: ... my understanding is that `ABC1001` should become `ABC11`

Comment: To clarify: `ABC1001` should be `ABC1001`! Thank you @JvdV to pointing there. @Tim Biegeleisen sorry for not clear expression. Maybe you could clarify.

Answer (score 4):

I think I'd go with 'sub' and use capture groups:

```
strings <- c("ABC0001", "ABC02", "ABC10", "ABC01010", "ABC11", "ABC011", "ABC0120", "ABC1001")
output <- sub("([A-Z])0+([1-9])", "\\1\\2", strings, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "ABC1"    "ABC2"    "ABC10"   "ABC1010" "ABC11"   "ABC11"   "ABC120"   "ABC1001"
```

Tested on [Jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-r-online/) and an online regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/5PJjWE/1)

---

- `([A-Z])` - Capture any uppercase letter in 1st group;
- `0+` - 1+ (Greedy) consecutive zero's;
- `([1-9])` - A single digit ranging 1-9 in a 2nd group. Note that you can remove this group if you are ok with 'ABC0000' to be 'ABC'!

Replace with `\1\2`.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. Also sharing `Jdoodle`. May I ask how did you accomplished the demo link that shows exactly this example?

Comment: I couldn't share the Jdoodle sample, just the website. There probably is a way though that when you log in you can share a project. IDK =). Just copy/paste the code in the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

We can try the code below

```
> sub("(\\D+)0+(.*)", "\\1\\2", strings)
[1] "ABC1"    "ABC2"    "ABC10"   "ABC1010" "ABC11"   "ABC11"   "ABC120"
```