# Error using data.table for output table generation

Tags: r, data.table

I would like some help regarding the adjustment of the second code. Codes are intended to do the same thing. The first code is generating the output table correctly. However, in the second code, which uses the `data.table` function does not. This second code was taken from here: [How adjust code functionality to specifications using data.table function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960232/how-adjust-code-functionality-to-specifications-using-data-table-function#) In the example that was done in the question, the result was right, but when I tested for my new database, it didn't give the expected result. The output table for that second code would also have to be `coef = 14` and `Result = 1`

Can you help me to solve it?

**libraries**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
```

**database**

```
df1<-structure(list(Id = 8, date1 = structure(1649376000, tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt")), date2 = structure(1649376000, tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt")), Week = "Friday", DT = "0", Category = "ABC", 
            GR = 1, DayR1 = 0, DayM000 = 13, DayM001 = 13, 
            DayM002 = 14, DayM003 = 14, DayM004 = 13, DayM005 = 13, DayM006 = 13, 
            DayM007 = 12, DayM008 = 12, DayM009 = 12, coef = 14), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L))
    
  Id      date1      date2   Week DT Category GR DayR1 DayM000 DayM001 DayM002 DayM003 DayM004 DayM005 DayM006 DayM007 DayM008 DayM009 coef
1  8 2022-04-08 2022-04-08 Friday  0      ABC  1     0      13      13      14      14      13      13      13      12      12      12   14
```

**First code (The result is correct)**

```
 df1%>% mutate(across(starts_with("Day"), ~coef - .),
                       across(contains("date"), ymd),
                       datedif = parse_number(as.character(date2-date1)))%>%
    rename_with(~str_replace(.,'(?<=[A-Z])0+(?=.)', ""), starts_with('Day')) %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(Result= if (str_c('DayM', datedif) %in% names(.)) get(str_c('DayM', datedif)) else coef) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
  select(coef, Result)%>%data.frame()

 coef Result
1   14   1
```

**Second Code (Using **data.table** function). The result is wrong**

```
dr_names <- grep("^Day", names(df1), value = TRUE)
date_names <- grep("date", names(df1), value = TRUE)
setDT(df1)[, (dr_names) := lapply(.SD, function(x) coef - x), .SDcols = dr_names
    ][, (date_names) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate), .SDcols = date_names
    ][, datedif := date2 - date1]
setnames(df1, dr_names, sub("([A-Z])0+", "\\1", dr_names))

   df1[,  .(coef, Result = fcoalesce(as.matrix(.SD)[cbind(.I,         
   match(paste0('DayM', datedif), names(.SD)))], coef)),       .SDcols = patterns("^DayM\\d+")]%>%data.frame()

  coef Result
1   14     14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the `sub` code with `setnames`.  The code matches one or more 0s (`0+`) after the uppercase letter `([A-Z])` and removes those in the replacement.  In the previous dataset, it worked because the names pattern was different.  Here, the names ends with digits for 'dr_names'

```
> dr_names
 [1] "DayR1"   "DayM000" "DayM001" "DayM002" "DayM003" "DayM004" "DayM005" "DayM006" "DayM007" "DayM008" "DayM009"
```

Thus, for the 'DayM000', it returns `DayM`, which wouldn't match correctly with `paste0("DayM", datedif)` which returns `DayM0`.  A change in the pattern to keep the last digit would fix it

```
setnames(df1, dr_names, sub("([A-Z])0+(.)", "\\1\\2", dr_names))
```

Now, we run the code

```
df1[,  .(coef, Result = fcoalesce(as.matrix(.SD)[cbind(.I,         
    match(paste0('DayM', datedif), names(.SD)))], coef)),  
       .SDcols = patterns("^DayM\\d+")]%>%
   data.frame()
  coef Result
1   14      1
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, one question please: this `df1` database that I used in this question, do you know what is the command to convert to `.json`?

Comment: @JVieira you can use `toJSON` from `jsonlite` and then write it to json